# How can I implement a deep/machine learning algorithm for this?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning

I have a known matrix, $\bf C$ of size $N\times B$. Each row has a fixed number of non-zero elements.

The demand vector is given by $d$ of size $1\times B$.

The supply vector $s$ of size $1\times B$ is given by

$s=\sum_{i=1}^T C_i\alpha_i$.

Here. $C_i$ is the $i$th row vector of known matrix, $\bf C$.

I have a large set of data for $d$ and corresponding $\alpha_i$s and $s$.

Now, I want a machine/deep learning algorithm that gives me $\alpha_i$s for a given $d$.

How can I implement a deep learning algorithm for this?

Comment: You appear to have lots of data records that could be simple inputs and outputs of a neural network. Could you clarify whether you know $C$ for all your examples, as it sets some useful constraints? Could you also clarify what prevents you simply making a neural network and training it on your known $d, \alpha$ pairs? This looks very straightforward (although you could maybe do better if you know $C$)

Comment: @NeilSlater, I am very new to this machine learning area. Let's say, C is known, which tool I can use to write the code?

Comment: It is easier to work without C. In that case you can write a neural network in any of a dozen different frameworks. The neural network design here could be very simple to start with. Are you saying that actually you have never used any neural network library? If that is the case, then no answer here is going to be suitable, as there is too much to learn in one go - just take an introductory course on data science and neural networks in whatever your preferred language is. I recommend Andrew Ng's courses on Coursera, but others are possible too. https://www.coursera.org/learn/machine-learning